# How to transfer android app to pc for storage

Tags: android

I have seen this question before on this site, but the solutions have eluded me.

I have an app that I like, an app no longer supported by the developer.  It's called DragonMobileApp.  I'd like to copy it to my PC so that I can add it to another phone that I own.

Unfortunately, I can't figure out where it is in the file system on my phone.  I've tried ADB and MyAppSharer and nothing seems to work for me.  (Not the least of which I think I'm not actually able to see all of the files on my phone.)

And, of course, if you help me solve this problem, then I'll need to figure out how to load it from my PC onto a phone.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.  I really did try all the solutions I found here before posting this question.

Answer (score 0):

- Install [Xplore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lonelycatgames.Xplore&hl=en) app from Store
- Open it and click on App Manager
- Click and hold the App and select Copy
- Select a folder from your memory card or a folder you'd want to copy the apk file to
- Click Ok to complete.

I'm guessing you don't need help to copy a file from your device to your PC.
Cheers!!!

Comment: Thanks!  I'll give it a shot.  Once I find it, I can copy it to my PC for safe keeping.

Comment: P.S.  It's a real shame Nuance quit supporting this product.  It's not robust, but it allows me to answer my phone, make phone calls, and handle my GPS programs, all hands free.  And it doesn't track me, like Google.  I'm willing to trade a little less convenience for leaving less personal data!